# Java's BigInteger implementation

Tags: java, biginteger

I'm new here so please excuse my noob mistakes. I'm currently working on a little project of mine that sees me dealing with digits with a length in the forty thousands and beyond.

I'm currently using BigInteger to handle these values, and I need something that performs faster. I've read that BigInteger uses an array of integers in its implementation, and what I need to know is whether BigInteger is using each index in this array to represent each decimal point, as in 1 - 9, or is it using something more efficient.

I ask this because I already have an implementation in mind that uses bit operations, which makes it more efficient, memory and processing wise.

So the final question is - is BigInteger already efficient enough, and should I just rely on that? It would better to know this rather than putting it to the test unnecessarily, which would take a lot of time.

Thank you.

Comment: Hard to tell *efficient enough*... You can write an benchmark and make a comparasion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: You've stated "I need something that performs faster" - is that conjecture on your part, or have you proved that `BigInteger` *isn't* already efficient enough for you? (I strongly suspect that any optimizations you can easily imagine for `BigInteger` are already present. You can check out the implementation yourself though, e.g. at https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/957de5be48bc/src/java.base/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java

Comment: soooo many applications use `BigInteger`, I doubt even a tiny fraction of them have potential bottle necks because of that

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone. And no I'm not making any assumptions. I just needed to know. Of course I understand that BigInteger is as refined and as sophisticated as they come, but when I read something about an array, it made me think of an old superint class I had made before finding the BigInteger class. I was working on the same project, and I jumped straight into making my own minimal SuperInt, but it was really slow, and I thought up an improvement, but by then I had also found BigInteger. So that's where my curiosity comes in.

Comment: And for anyone wondering what an app would be doing with such digits; right now I'm basically still developing an algorithm rather than an app, and most of my uses of BigInteger are for tests, so to say.

Comment: In my limited testing I haven't found any pure Java big int implementations that are faster than Java 8+ BigInteger, including third party classes that claim they are faster. Java 8+ BigInteger incorporates advanced algorithms that perform better than O(n^2) for multiplication and division on sufficiently large operands.

Comment: Thanks. That's also quite useful. I'll stick with the fastest then. Haha, now I can imagine why one would want to bite my head off for talking about custom implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least with Oracle's Java 8 and OpenJDK 8, it doesn't store one decimal digit per `int`. It stores full 32-bit portions per 32-bit `int` in the `int[]`, which can be seen with [its source code](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java).

Bit operations are fast for it, since it's a sign-magnitude value and the magnitude is stored packed just as you'd expect, just make sure that you use [the relevant `BigInteger` bitwise methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#method.summary) rather than implementing your own.

If you still need more speed, try something like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/), though be aware that it uses a LGPL or GPL license. It would also be better to use it outside of Java.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I'll just focus on BigInteger.